# Change CSS class on click in Stenciljs

Tags: css, stenciljs

Is it possible to use the simple menu animation from W3School in Stencil.js?

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_icon_js

I'm trying to set the styling on a click event, but I can't make it work. The event is fireing but I can't set the class.

In my .tsx:

```
import { Component, Prop, h } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'topbar-component',
  styleUrl: 'topbar-component.css',
  shadow: true
})

export class Topbar {

  private menuToggle(e) {
    return (
      e.classList.toggle("change");
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="topbar-menu">
        <div class="container" onClick={(e) => this.menuToggle(e)}>
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In my css:

```
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

I get error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

Comment: for all it's worth (because the post is already a bit older...): you are trying to get the classList of an event. But the class list sits on the .targetElement of the event, like it is shown in the last example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do it using a state property:

```
import { Component, Prop, State, h } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'topbar-component',
  styleUrl: 'topbar-component.css',
  shadow: true
})

export class Topbar {

  @State() isMenuOpen: boolean = false;

  private menuToggle() {
    this.isMenuOpen = !this.isMenuOpen;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="topbar-menu">
        <div class={{ container: true, change: this.isMenuOpen }}" onClick={(e) => this.menuToggle(e)}>
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats probably a better way of doing it. I will try it out!

Answer (score 2):

I made it work. I found the classlist at last.

So just add this to your menuToggle()

```
  private menuToggle(e) {
    return (
      e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("change")
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked for me. I had to add the class in parent element of clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code can be usefuel for handling your question:

```
    import { Component, Prop, h } from '@stencil/core';
    @Component({
      tag: 'topbar-component',
      styleUrl: 'topbar-component.css',
      shadow: true
    })
    
    export class Topbar {
    
      private menuToggle() {
        this.isMenuOpen = !this.isMenuOpen
      }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="topbar-menu">
         {this.isMenuOpen
                ?
                <div class=container change" onClick={() => this.menuToggle()}>
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
               </div>
                :
               <div class=container" onClick={() => this.menuToggle()}>
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
               </div>
              }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```